# How to customize login.html while using Secure Module in play framework

Tags: security, module, playframework

I am newbie to play. Since I am using Secure Module in play framework with japid. I have designed the custom login templete and called the templete in "beforeLogin.html" tag. I need to show my custom login templete instead of Secure Module's login.html templete. I have tried to override login.html using play secure:ov --login. It successfully overrides the login page and puts the page locally in Secure folder. But I need to user my own custom login page instead of Secure Module's login.html

Answer (score 5):

Create a file `login.html` in `views/Secure`. (And create the folder `Secure` if is doesn't exist, of course)

Comment: Thanks for the instant reply Zenklys.
But as we override the login.html file using play secure:ov --login, framework will create the required structure i.e it will create the views/Secure/login.html. Since I am using japid, my custom login form is in app\japidview.XYZ. I need to show this login form whenever User request for any of the page in my application (if he is not logged in) .

Comment: As said before on the other post that was deleted, Japid is a one person module. Please contact the author for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you can override the Secure module controller by extending the `Secure.Security` class. I'd suggest extend the `SecureSocial` class and override `login()` to `renderJapid()`. Then use this controller in the `@With` annotation. I presume this would solve your problem.